# Write NSString in text file in iOS without overwrite Data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app, i need to write into a file without overwrite existing data. My code is:

```m
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//creating a path
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file"];

//creating NSFileHandle and seeking for the end of file
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:appFile];
[fh seekToEndOfFile];

//appending data do the end of file
NSString *dataString = @"Some Data";
NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[fh writeData:data];
```

The code creates the file, but every time it's opened the content is overwritten. Some solutions?

Comment: What is the offset returned by `seekToEndOfFile`? And you verify the file contents at the end of the test?

Comment: I think your code should work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is not an optimal solution if the file is huge.

You have to read the contents of the file into a string. Append the string with the new data. And write back the string to the file. Something like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//creating a path
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file"];

 //Retriving contents of the file
NSStringEncoding enco;
NSMutableString *logStr = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:appFile usedEncoding:&enco error:nil];

NSString *dataString = @"Some Data";
[logStr appendString:@"\n"];
[logStr appendString:dataString];
[logStr writeToFile:appFile atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: @CarloM_dtb I would be good to know why your code doesn't work, as it looks OK to me.  How do you examine the file contents after writing them?  Does the file handle get closed before this happens?

Comment: Hold on.  While your solution *works* it's **very suboptimal** (as you state yourself), given that file could be huge and could cause the app's memory footprint to balloon.  I don't think you should be suggesting this as **the** solution, just so you can earn some more *rep*.

Comment: -1 @CarloM_dtb Well done guys you've just encouraged one hundred more coders to write crap code.

Comment: @trojanfoe i don't really know why my code don't works, i've make a control on [fh seekToEndOfFile] and it seems that don't works fine.

Comment: @CarloM_dtb You didn't answer my question.  Does the file handle get closed before the file is examined?  Show how you examine the file contents.

Comment: @trojanfoe the code works for me, have you got a better solution? I examine the file contents by open it with a simple textedit.
   if ([fh seekToEndOfFile]) {
                    NSLog(@"works");
               } else {
                   NSLog(@"error");
               }

Comment: @CarloM_dtb **DOES THE FILE HANDLE GET CLOSED BEFORE YOU EXAMINE THE FILE?**

Comment: trojanfoe: i dint answer the question to gain reputation. If so, i wouldn't have mentioned that it is not an optimal solution. Feel free to down vote the answer

Comment: OK that's fine; you have acknowledged your answer isn't optimal for a huge file.  I am somewhat frustrated that the OP is not interested in finding the correct answer to this issue and is simply interested in solving his own issues.  This does nothing to help others.  I am also frustrated that you encouraged him to accept your answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe you should use better mode when interact with other people. The -1 give to my answer it's the behavior of a child.

Comment: @CarloM_dtb No, I will continue to operate in this way. I downvoted your question as you are clearly only here to solve your own issues and are not interested in finding out why your current code doesn't work in order to help others.  As it stands this question will do more harm than good to anyone with a similar issue and therefore I downvoted to warn others off.

Comment: I've answer you before, but you has not notice it.